# sending a list over python3 socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sockets

I have been trying for 2 days to send a list with 40,000 items which each have 3 items inside of them(its just a list in a list).
I am trying to get a server to send over the list to a client so they can render it using pygame. unfortuanatly I am bad a research and existing properly so nothing has worked. I have tried pickle and json. I might have done them wrong tho.

/server.py

```
def threaded_client(conn):
     while True:
        conn.send(json.dumps(cubes).encode())
def  stuffs():
    while True:
        cubes = Sgeneration.cubes.list
        s.listen()
        conn,data = s.accept()
        if not conn in humans:
            humans.append(conn)
            start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
        Sgeneration.generate.draw(gameDisplay)
        pygame.display.update()
stuffs()
```

/generation.py

```
def draw(window):
    global cubes
    g = s.recv(4096)
    g = json.loads(data)

    print(type(g))
    for x in g.get("a"):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,x[2],[(x[0]*distance+offset[0]),x[1]*distance+offset[1],distance,distance])
```

Comment: If your list contains 40000 items, then a single call to `.recv(4096)` is certainly not going to get all of it.  As is *always* the case with TCP connections, it's up to you to provide some way for the other end to know that the entire payload is received.  The basic choices are to close the connection after the send (resulting in a 0 byte read after everything else has been read), adding a delimiter character or string that cannot appear in the data itself (reading until you see that delimiter), or sending the length of the data in advance (reading until you've received that much data).

Comment: I think I understand what your saying. so let me try it. Thank you for your response

Comment: I get this error for the json loading. what do I do now 

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1075974 (char 1075973)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. what I did was only send the entire thing at the begging of the connection. I also sent it in small portions. When I transmitted back to every client I only sent the stuff that had changed. This suprisingly worked. took a while.